# Puppet: Conditional file source based on naming convention

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

I'm getting the ball rolling on puppet for my environment - and I'd like to have a conditional `file` resource based on whether or not the module itself contains a file based on a naming convention.

So visually, assume a module named 'mysql' and it's layout:

```
mysql/
    /files
        /etc/
            my.cnf
            my.hostname1.cnf
            my.hostname2.cnf
     /manifests
            init.pp
...
```

So I'd like the block to verify if the resource for the module exists or not, and take action accordingly, in pseudo-terms:

```
file { '/etc/my.cnf':

  if -f 'puppet:///mysql/etc/my.$hostname.cnf' {
      source => 'puppet:///mysql/etc/my.$hostname.cnf'
  }
  else {
      source => 'puppet:///mysql/etc/my.cnf'
  }
}
```

This way one wouldn't have to manage a csv file or the `.pp` file with a host specific case statement - is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The current [resource file type documentation](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/types/file.html) specifies you can do `file{'/etc/my.cnf': source => [ "puppet:///mysql/etc/my.$hostname.cnf" , "puppet:///mysql/etc/my.cnf" ]
}`

Comment: That's a big ol 'DOH, RTFM' for me, shame >.<  - thanks!